# Limit of function with $\frac00$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am unable to solve following limit:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0_+}\frac{\sin \sqrt{x}}{x^2}\left(\sqrt{x+2x^2}-\sqrt{2\sqrt{1+x}-2}\right)$$
I keep getting  $ \frac{0}{0}$. I admit I haven't tried to use l'Hospital rule multiple times as the square root  is not so nice to derive more than one time. Is it possible to solve this limit without using l'Hospital rule/Taylor series (which I haven't learned yet)?
Thank you

Comment: Try multiplying the top and bottom by the conjugate.

Comment: @cryogenic : I would start by replacing $x$ with $t^2$ to get rid of the square root.  Use $\sin(t)/t \to 1$ as $t \to 0$ (which does not require either of the two things you mentioned).  No more $\sin$.

Comment: ok so if i replace x^2 by t, I also have to add another square roots into the existing square roots? Or what you are trying to suggest is that I "divide" x^2 to have $\frac{\sin{\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x}}\codt \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\sqrt{2\sqrt{1+x}-2}\sim\sqrt{x+2x^2}\sim\sqrt x$, while
\begin{align}
(x+2x^2)-(2\sqrt{1+x}-2)
&=2x^2+x+2-2\sqrt{1+x}\\
&=\frac{(2x^2+x+2)^2-4(1+x)}{2x^2+x+2+2\sqrt{1+x}}\\
&\sim\frac 94x^2
\end{align}
thus
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin \sqrt{x}}{x^2}(\sqrt{x+2x^2}-\sqrt{2\sqrt{1+x}-2})
&=\frac{\sin \sqrt{x}}{x^2}\frac{(x+2x^2)-(2\sqrt{1+x}-2)}{\sqrt{x+2x^2}+\sqrt{2\sqrt{1+x}-2}}\\
&\sim \frac{\sqrt x}{x^2}\frac{\frac 94x^2}{2\sqrt x}\\
&=\frac 98
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for answering, but this solution uses Taylor series right?

Comment: No, it's elementary, only asympthotic notation is required such as $\sin(x)\sim x$ and $\sqrt{1+x}\sim \frac 12x$.

Comment: I tried to google it, and it looks interesting, but is elementary to the extent that such thing would be covered in intro class of analysis?

Comment: Yes, it's simply a notation; for example $\sin(x)\sim x$ is another way to write $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}x=1$, while $\sqrt{1+x}-1\sim \frac 12x$ follows from $\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-1}x=\frac{1+x-1}{x(\sqrt{1+x}+1)}\to\frac 12$.

Comment: alright, I am going to go through your solution(it takes a lot of time for me) and I will comment later if I need some clarification.

Comment: okay I see it now after I took a break, I guess I was just too tired to understand anything. :)

Comment: @Fabio Lucchini Respected Sir ,Can you please me On 1^st line how to do that approximation and also i had not understand 4 th line .How to Obtained that ?

Comment: It follows from $\sqrt {1+x}-1\sim x/2$ as $x\to 0$.